# Black screen at start up of app wear os watch app

Tags: android, wear-os, watch, android-watch

I am facing a black screen at the startup of the application sometimes.

Here is the code of splash, where I think I am not using any main thread blocking code if yes then it should block after 1.2 sec lol.

```
public class Splash extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        findViewById(R.id.ivLogo).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                App app = (App) getApplication();
                app.initializeSingletons();

                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,NewHome.class));
                finish();
            }
        },1200);
    }
}
```

BaseActivity code look like this,

```
public class BaseActivity extends WearableActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
}
```

The problem, when I click on the app from the app list of wear it was showing **black screen** for **1 sec or 2 sec sometimes**.
Anyone facing this issue?

**Watch Details** :

Watch: `Fossil Sports`
OS: `Wear Os By Google 2.10`
System Version: `H MR1`

compiled and `targetSdkVersion` version is `29`

Comment: so it is showing black screen for 1 or 2 seconds, then splash screen for 1.2 seconds then Home ? or after black screen directly to home ?

Comment: @rajan.kali yes some time, when i open it again its works normal